# Adding ES7 Decorator support to a React Native project

Tags: react-native

I want to allow for my React Native application to use `Decorators`, but how do I achieve this?

In React, it's pretty simple:

1. I ran `yarn run eject`
2. I modified `webpack.config.*.js` and added `plugins: ['transform-decorators-legacy']`

How do I achieve something similar with `react-native`? I instantiated my project via the react-native CLI - `react-native init AwesomeApp`.

However, the `eject` command doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you're developing an application using only React Native CLI, you don't have access to configuration files such as `webpack.config.js`, or an `eject` command.

But you can add `decorators` support through the same Babel plugin, just by modifying `.babelrc` file. Follow the steps below:

1. Install the plugin to your project (as a dev dependency): `yarn add --dev babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy`;
2. Declare the plugin in your `.babelrc` file: `"plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]`;

Now, next time you start the `packager` (or bundle the sources), React Native will be able to interpret the decorators you've used in your JavaScript files.

The example given in [this article](http://moduscreate.com/using-es2016-decorators-in-react-native/) shows exactly what I have described above.

Also, you might take a look at [Haul](https://github.com/callstack-io/haul), a tool for creating React Native apps using `webpack`.

Good luck!