# React Native decorator support not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-next

I've attempted to use React Native Props Mapper which uses decorators in the API. I have followed the instructions on several sites including the following Stack issue:

[Adding ES7 Decorator support to a React Native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43983272/adding-es7-decorator-support-to-a-react-native-project)

***Component:***

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, ScrollView } from 'react-native'
import { Container } from 'native-base';
import { List, ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { withMappedNavigationProps } from 'react-navigation-props-mapper'

import styles from './styles';
import Storage from '../../../../../services/storage';
import Utils from '../../../../../services/utils';

import SessionManager from '../../../../../services/session-management/session-manager';

import * as sessionActions from '../../../../../data/screens/session/actions/session';
import * as listActions from '../../../../../data/screens/session/actions/session-list';
import * as listItemActions from '../../../../../data/screens/session/actions/session-list-item';
import * as userActions from '../../../../../data/shared/user/actions/user';

import Constants from '../../../../../constants';

@withMappedNavigationProps()
class Listing extends Component {


}
```

Package JSON:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel-jest": "22.2.2",
  "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
  "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0": "^1.0.1",
  "jest": "22.2.2",
  "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
}
```

***.babelrc:***

```
{
  "presets": [
    "react-native",
    "react-native-stage-0/decorator-support",
    "transform-decorators-legacy"
  ],
    "plugins": [
        "transform-decorators-legacy"
    ]
}
```

When I attempt to build I get the following error:

[image]

Additionally I tried to use react-native-stage-0/decorator-support which is also seen in the .baberc file and that did not work either.

Any assist is appreciated.

Thanks.